# Recibir parámetros dinámicos en Postgresql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, funciones, parámetros

Tengo un problema y es que no sé cuál es la forma de insertar valores en una tabla donde se desconoce la cantidad de valores (parámetros) que se van a recibir desde una aplicación (web), por ejemplo el detalle de una factura puede tener un producto como puede tener 10  ¿cómo puedo recibir todos los productos pertenecientes al detalle y luego insertarlos?

Nota: La aplicacion web es en Java y el gestor de bd es PostgreSql

-Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## insertando un array JSON en múltiples registros de una tabla PostgreSQL

La mejor variante (en especial si los datos vienen desde la web o sea que están en un objeto javascript) es mandar los renglones en un `array json` y el encabezado de la factura en un `objeto json`.

Por ejemplo si la estructura es:

```
create table facturas(
  numero integer primary key,
  fecha date,
  cliente text
);

create table renglones_fac(
  numero integer,
  renglon integer,
  producto text,
  cantidad decimal,
  precio decimal,
  primary key (numero, renglon)
);
alter table renglones_fac
  add foreign key (numero) references facturas (numero)
    on delete cascade;
```

Las inserciones se pueden hacer utilizando las funciones `jsonb_populate_record` y `jsonb_populate_recorset` (ver https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html). Así:

```
insert into facturas select *
  from jsonb_populate_record(null::facturas, '{"fecha": "2018-10-25", "numero": 2, "cliente": "github"}'::jsonb);

insert into renglones_fac select *
  from jsonb_populate_recordset(null::renglones_fac,
    '[{"numero": 2, "precio": 25.50, "renglon": 1, "cantidad": 1, "producto": "P1"}, {"numero": 2, "precio": 12.99, "renglon": 2, "cantidad": 2, "producto": "P2"}]');
```

Es probable también que necesites hacer la operación inversa (o sea obtener esos dos objetos `JSON` para enviárselos en el mismo formato al frontend:

```
select to_jsonb(f.*) as encabezado, 
   (select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(r.*))
      from renglones_fac as r 
      where r.numero=f.numero) as renglones
  from facturas as f;
```

Answer (score 2):

Supongamos que tienes una tabla de facturas y una tabla de productos. Ambos tienen un cierto ID como llave única. Luego tienes una tabla de relación `factura_producto` que contiene `id_factura` y `id_producto`.

Entiendo que lo que buscas es llenar la tabla `factura_producto` dado un ID factura y uno o más productos.

La solución más simple, aunque poco elegante, sería concatenar los ids de los productos, por ejemplo usando `|` y luego insertar convirtiendo el string de productos concatenados (e.g. `1|2|3|4`) a un arreglo de enteros. Por ejemplo, si es la factura N°1:

```
INSERT INTO producto_factura
SELECT 1 as id_factura, unnest(string_to_array('1|2|3|4','|')::integer[]) as id_producto;
```

La función `unnest` convierte cada elemento de un array en un registro, por lo cual la ejecución de:

```
SELECT 1 as id_factura, unnest(string_to_array('1|2|3|4','|')::integer[]) as id_producto;
```

Es un recordset de la forma:

```
id_factura | id_producto
------------------------
     1     |     1
     1     |     2
     1     |     3
     1     |     4
```

Donde ambos campos son enteros.

Hay maneras más elegantes de hacer lo mismo sin ponerte a concatenar los ids (lo cual implica pasar un array de enteros a un string) Por ejemplo, podrías crear una función que espere como parámetros `factura` (integer) y un array `productos` (integer[]).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inserta_producto_factura(factura integer, productos integer[])
RETURNS SETOF producto_factura  AS
$$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY INSERT INTO producto_factura
           WITH lista_productos AS (
             SELECT unnest(productos) as producto_id
           )
           SELECT factura, lista_productos.producto_id
           FROM lista_productos
           RETURNING  id_factura, id_producto  ;

END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Básicamente, la función espera que la llamen como:

```
SELECT * FROM inserta_producto_factura(5,[1,2,3,4]);
```

Por dentro ejecuta una query que contiene una subquery definida con `WITH lista_productos (...)` en donde cada elemento del array de productos se convierte en un registro gracias a la función `unnest`.

Luego se inserta en `producto_factura` la factura que ingresaste como primer parámetro y los registros provenientes de `lista_productos`.

Añadí a la query la cláusula RETURNING para que la salida de la función sea un listado de los registros que se acaban de insertar.

Para usar esta función, siempre tienes que pasar los productos como un array. Si es un sólo producto, entonces la llamas simplemente como:

```
SELECT * FROM inserta_producto_factura(5,[1]);
```